# Asp.Net Post Nested List of Files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Unfortunately, I have been stuck getting my api to work and experiencing some strange behavior. In order to post files along with some satellite data, it works as follows:

[image]

With the following model:

```
public class SomeDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IFormFileCollection Files { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I created a nested Object and moved the `Files` property into that object, like so:

```
public class FilesUploadDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Remote { get; set; }
    public IFormFileCollection Local { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public FilesUploadDTO Files { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my screenshot from Postman. Everything gets posted besides the `Files.Local` which is always empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `files.local` instead, here's my test result:

[image]

[This section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#complex-types) remind me to write like this format.

Comment: You are right, that worked. Thanks for your input.